# How different is ‘to unwind’ from ‘to relax’?

Tags: word-usage, differences, connotation

The other day I came across the phrase ‘I need to unwind.’ and I found it means ‘I need to relax’, which I’m familiar with.  Can both be used exactly in the same way or are there any differences in its connotations?

Comment: 'Relax' is the opposite of activity. One is in a state of relaxation, or repose. 'Unwind' indicates a previous state of tension or stress or 'being wound up'.

Answer (score 2):

"**unwind**" in the sense of personally relaxing is a recent and figurative term.  The OED first notes this use of "unwind" in 1958:

> **d. fig. To relieve from tension or anxiety, to cause to relax**. colloq. 
>   1958   B. Malamud in Partisan Rev. Spring 180   He managed to
>   unwind himself and relax.

Think of winding a watch or a clock . . . when they had springs.

By contrast, for **"relax"** the OED has this and related definitions with citations going back to the 17th century:

> ** b. intr. To cease or lessen one's efforts; to rest; to seek or take  recreation.**

What you don't want to do is to assume that these are synonyms that can be swapped back and forth.  Each has its use--or uses.

Answer (score 0):

A square is a rectangle, but a rectangle is not necessarily a square.  Similarity, relaxing is a way to unwind, but unwinding is not necessarily relaxing.

For example, doing a task that is physically exhausting (exercise, chopping wood) is a good way to unwind.  You can unwind and relax at a spa, but you can only unwind at a boxing match.

Comment: I find boxing particularly relaxing actually.